# MySQL include zero rows when using COUNT with LEFT OUTER JOIN and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, left-join

How can I avoid eliminating the users with zero meetings? I'm aware there are similar questions, but this code is quite a bit more complex.

```
SELECT user.userID, user.contactName, user.email, COUNT( * ) AS meetingsCount
FROM user
LEFT OUTER JOIN meeting ON user.userID = meeting.userID
WHERE user.userID NOT 
IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 59, 62, 63, 64, 66, 69, 71, 72, 73, 78, 107 ) 
AND SUBSTRING( meeting.meetingCode, 5, 2 ) 
BETWEEN 12 
AND 22 
AND SUBSTRING( meeting.meetingCode, 7, 2 ) 
BETWEEN 01 
AND 12 
AND SUBSTRING( meeting.meetingCode, 9, 2 ) 
BETWEEN 01 
AND 31 
GROUP BY user.userID, contactName, email
ORDER BY meetingsCount DESC
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the logic for the meeting code table in your join.  Otherwise users matching the records you are filtering out from the meeting table will be filtered out of your results.  Making your JOIN essentially an INNER join.  I think you also should put single quotes around the values in your BETWEEN clauses.

```
SELECT  user.userID, user.contactName, user.email, COUNT( meeting.userID ) AS meetingsCount

FROM    user

        LEFT OUTER JOIN meeting ON user.userID = meeting.userID
        AND SUBSTRING( meeting.meetingCode, 5, 2 ) BETWEEN '12' AND '22'
        AND SUBSTRING( meeting.meetingCode, 7, 2 ) BETWEEN '01' AND '12'
        AND SUBSTRING( meeting.meetingCode, 9, 2 ) BETWEEN '01' AND '31' 

WHERE user.userID NOT IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 59, 62, 63, 64, 66, 69, 71, 72, 73, 78, 107 ) 

GROUP BY user.userID, contactName, email

ORDER BY meetingsCount DESC
```

Comment: Hey this kind of fixes it, but users with no meetings are being counted as having one.

Comment: My bad.  You can do a count of any non-NULL field in the meeting table.  I updated my SQL statement.

Comment: @JW - It happens to the best of us.  :)

Comment: Great thanks, it works now I edited COUNT(*) to COUNT( meeting.userID )

Comment: The COUNT function will count any non-NULL values.  I used userID since I new that would not be NULL if there was a match.